# merging array into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm creating an array using "push"

so the result is [Object, Object]

in there the code looks like:

```
[Object, Object]
    0: Object
        type: Array[6]
    1: Object
       type: Array[4]
```

I would like to combine both object and get a result like this:

```
["Mike", "Matt", "Nancy", "Adam", "Jenny", "Carl", "Jim", "Issac", "Lee", "Won"]
```

I have no idea to get this to work, any suggestion?

code sample:

```
    dropdown: function(data) {
        var arr = [];

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            arr.push({
                type: value.type
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: well, but i can have more that 2 obj, they can be 10. i'm just looping thr and pushing them to one array.

Comment: Could you share the code that actually creates the array; it would also be nice to explain what kind of objects you're talking about.

Comment: ok - i added in the post

Comment: Do you need to remove duplicates? Your title says `merge`, but most of the answers use `concat`, which just appends one array to another.

Comment: no, i don't need to, I will remove duplicates later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple loop:

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    $.merge(result, object[i].type);
}
```

Comment: something like this:?    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    arr.push({
     type: value.type
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     $.merge(arr, arr[i].type);
    }
   });

Comment: This code shouldn't be in your `$.each` loop, it's something you do after, once the array of objects is created.

Answer (score 4):

You can concatenate one array onto another with [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```
arr = arr.concat(otherArr);
```

Note that `concat` creates a new array, leaving the original unchanged, which is why you have to re-assign it.

Note - for three arrays, you can just keep passing them in.

```
var arr1 = [0,1];
var arr2 = [2,3];
var arr3 = [4,5];

arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2, arr3);

console.log(arr1);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63eYy/)

---

EDIT

You mentioned having dynamic arrays.  I'm not sure what you mean by that, but I'll note that if you have an arbitrary array of arrays, and you want them all concated, you can do this

```
var arr1 = [0,1];
var arr2 = [2,3];
var arr3 = [4,5];

var otherArrays = [arr2, arr3];

arr1 = Array.prototype.concat.apply(arr1, otherArrays);

console.log(arr1);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8HL6X/2/)

Comment: he wants to merge, not concatenate.

Comment: how will this work with let say 3 array? can otherArr be = to arr1, arr2, arr3?

Comment: `arr = arr1.concat(arr2).concat(arr3)`

Comment: um, but the arr(s) are been created dynamically,  I would know how many they are. not sure if i'm making myself clear

Comment: I'm not sure why it matters whether or not the arrays are created dynamically.  You still have access to the arrays, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use `concat`, like this

```
arr1=["apple","orange","pineapple","pomegranate"];
arr2=["pizza","candy","chocolate","tasty"];
arr3=["food","drink"];
concatted=arr1.concat(arr2).concat(arr3);
```

You can keep chaining together arrays like that for as long as you want, until you run out of memory

Alternatively, you can just do this

```
concatted=arr1.concat(arr2,arr3);
```

If you want to remove duplicates, you can use this

```
Array.prototype.removeDuplicates=function(){
    var newArray=[];
    for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++){
        if(newArray.indexOf(this[i])==-1){
            newArray.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: +1 - not sure why some people are insisting on using jQuery for something that's simply native to the language

Comment: Because jQuery is great and does all the things! If you don't use it your a idiot (credit to bobince)

Comment: The pony, he comes :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified that you can use jquery, check out the `merge()` function: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/

Comment: i think merge() only work for 2 array, I dont know the # of array that i will be merging :/ - they can be 2 or 20.

Comment: Write a loop, what's the problem?

Comment: jQuery is great and does all the things. But in this case, I think `concat` is best

Comment: @scrblnrd3 `concat` won't remove duplicates, will it?

Comment: Reading the docs, it doesn't look like merge removes duplicates, either.

Comment: @Barmar but you can just use a loop, like I did in my answer